# Non-exhaustive patterns in function distance error stemming from where statement that shouldn't be reached

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and working on a [Hamming distance exercise](http://rosalind.info/problems/hamm/).

```
module Hamming (distance) where

distance :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
distance (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | lengthX /= lengthY  = Nothing
  | lengthX == 0        = Just 0
  | otherwise           = Just (headDistance + tailDistance)
  where
    lengthX = length (x:xs)
    lengthY = length (y:ys)
    headDistance = if x /= y then 1 else 0
    (Just tailDistance) = distance xs ys
```

When I run it, `distance "" ""` gives the error:

```
haskell/hamming » stack test
hamming> test (suite: test)


distance
  empty strands FAILED [1]

Failures:

  src/Hamming.hs:4:1:
  1) distance empty strands
       uncaught exception: PatternMatchFail
       src/Hamming.hs:(4,1)-(12,40): Non-exhaustive patterns in function distance

  To rerun use: --match "/distance/empty strands/"

Randomized with seed 892503112

Finished in 0.0003 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

hamming> Test suite test failed
Test suite failure for package hamming-2.3.0.10
    test:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```

I used guards instead of pattern matching for the main stuff, so it looks like it's that last where statement is the only place where pattern matching occurs, and must be what is causing the error. I see that it doesn't match against the `Nothing` output.

However, I don't see how it could ever produce `Nothing`, since things get evaluated lazily, I thought. In the case where the original strings are of different lengths, `Nothing` will be returned immediately and `distance` will never be called recursively, right?

Comment: the empty string does not match `(x:xs)` or `(y:ys)` - and that's your problem here

Comment: @RobinZigmond Gotcha that was it, thanks! I overlooked that and was focused on that `where` statement but it makes sense in retrospect. If you'd like to write up your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: If you turn on `-Wall`, GHC will tell you when your patterns are non-exhaustive — very useful in cases like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error isn't anything to do with your guards - it's much more basic than that.

You have:

```
distance :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
distance (x:xs) (y:ys)
- -  more code
```

but no other cases. So you do indeed have non-exhaustive patterns, because the only case you cover is when the first argument matches `(x:xs)`, and the second `(y:ys)` so it will crash as soon as either argument is empty - let alone both, as you are calling it here.